# Loop through elements with matching data attribute values

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following setup:

```js
    $( document ).on( 'click touch', '.target', function() {
        if ($(this).data("post-id") == $(this).closest('.list').find('.target').data("post-id")) {
           alert('do stuff');
        }
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="list">
  <div><div class="target" data-post-id="1">a</div></div>
  <div><div class="target" data-post-id="2">b</div></div>
  <div><div class="target" data-post-id="1">a</div></div>
  <div><div class="target" data-post-id="1">a</div></div>
  <div><div class="target" data-post-id="2">b</div></div>
</div>
```

Whenever user clicks on `.target` element, I want to *do stuff* to all divs within the closest `.list`. So if user clicks on `.target` with `post-id` data value `1`,  it should so something to all others with the same data attribute value...

How do I do this type of loop with jQuery?

Comment: `.each()` should do the trick. See [here](https://api.jquery.com/each/).

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca I actually tried `.each()` but couldn't make it work. Can you please demonstrate via an answer?

Comment: `jeffdill2` seems to already have demonstrated the use of `each()` to you in your previous question. In addition you said you tried `.each()` so please post **that** code to demonstrate the issue. Also, please see https://api.jquery.com/each/ for information on how to use it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just grab the ID and then find the rest - no need for each:

```js
$(document).on('click touch', '.target', function() {
  var id = $(this).data("post-id"), $list=$(this).closest(".list");
  $list.find(".target").removeClass("red") // reset in list
  $list.find(".target[data-post-id=" + id + "]").addClass("red"); // set same IDs
});
```

```css
.red {
  color: red
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="list">
  <div>
    <div class="target" data-post-id="1">a</div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div class="target" data-post-id="2">b</div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div class="target" data-post-id="1">a</div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div class="target" data-post-id="1">a</div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div class="target" data-post-id="2">b</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Just loop through all the elements that has the same `data-post-id` value as the clicked element using jQuery's `each()`.

```js
$( document ).on( 'click touch', '.target', function() {
    $("[data-post-id=" + $(this).data('post-id') + "]").each(function(){
        $(this).css("color", "red");
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="list">
  <div><div class="target" data-post-id="1">a</div></div>
  <div><div class="target" data-post-id="2">b</div></div>
  <div><div class="target" data-post-id="1">a</div></div>
  <div><div class="target" data-post-id="1">a</div></div>
  <div><div class="target" data-post-id="2">b</div></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

There are more ways how to achieve the result.

I've add removing classname from previous run, it puts a red color to just last selected items.

```js
$( document ).on( 'click touch', '.target', function() {
    var postID = $(this).data("post-id");
    
    $('.red').removeClass('red');
    
    $('.target').each(function() {
        var el = $(this);

        if (el.data('post-id') == postID) {
            el.addClass('red');
        }
    });
});
```

```css
.red {background: red}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="list">
  <div><div class="target" data-post-id="1">a</div></div>
  <div><div class="target" data-post-id="2">b</div></div>
  <div><div class="target" data-post-id="1">a</div></div>
  <div><div class="target" data-post-id="1">a</div></div>
  <div><div class="target" data-post-id="2">b</div></div>
</div>
```